# How to change a yielded value

Tags: python, python-3.x, yield, contextmanager

The following code uses a context manager to store and load variables into files.
However, it's very annoying to have to set the `value` property of what is yielded by the context manager (`loaded.value`).
I would like to

1. Not have to define a new class like `LoadedValue`
2. Set the yielded value of the context manager (`loaded`) to be the value that is saved.

Solving either of these issues would be appreciated.

```
import os
import pickle
from contextlib import contextmanager

class LoadedValue:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "<LoadedValue: {}>".format(self.value)

@contextmanager
def load_manager(load_file="file.pkl"):
    with open(load_file, "rb") as f:
        loaded_object = LoadedValue(pickle.load(f))
    try:
        yield loaded_object
    finally:
        with open(load_file, "wb+") as f:
            pickle.dump(loaded_object.value, f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "test.pkl"
    with open(filename, "wb+") as f:
        pickle.dump(7, f)

    with load_manager(filename) as loaded:
        print(loaded) # >>> <LoadedValue: 7>
        loaded.value = 5 # this is what I have to do
        # loaded = 5  # this is what I want to do

    with load_manager(filename) as loaded:
        print(loaded) # >>> <LoadedValue: 5>
```

Note: This was [originally posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211517/use-a-context-manager-to-save-an-object-on-exit) on CodeReview, but I have decided to repost it here in order to get answers, and leave it on CodeReview to help improve the code in other ways.

Comment: nope there is no assignment overload in python so you have to attach it to something ... and things in that scope are not accessible to the place that yielded the loaded_object ... so you have to attach it (you could override `+=` or something if you wanted to ... or you could do something like loaded(5) by defining a `__call__` method of your LoadedValue class

Comment: @JoranBeasley If you'd like to add that as an answer I'll accept it for now (unless someone comes up with a way to do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no there is no way to override the assignment operator in python, so you cannot do `loaded = 5`

(you could override other things so it might sort of work)

- override `__call__` to allow `loaded(5)`
- override `__lshift__` to allow `loaded << 5`
- override `__ior__` to allow `loaded |= 5`

(however be forwarned your coworkers, or future co workers may never forgive you)

also, things that occure within the scope of the `with XXXX as Y:` block are not (typically) accessible to the method that is yielding the context, unless that scope was previously accessible to the place yielding the scope (ie the global namespace etc)